# How to query Xml file using java

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing

I am having Xml file which contains about 50 Tables  `<tables></tables>`. All tables are linked to each other.

```
<table name="Information">
        <row>
            <field name="aggregateMID">123</field>
            <field name="MID">345</field>
            <field name="sequenceNum">1</field>
        </row>
        <row>
            <field name="aggregateMID">123</field>
            <field name="MID">346</field>
            <field name="sequenceNum">2</field>
        </row>
</table>
```

Can it be possible to query xml according to linking and fetch all required information? Please suggest what methods and API's will help me to do this job.

Comment: It's certainly possible. The problem is that there are too many good answers, depending on the needs of your application. The SAX and DOM APIs, XPath, XSLT and XQuery, JAXB, StAX, .... and that's just the tip of the iceberg. Without knowing a LOT more about exactly what you're trying to do, I wouldn't want to offer a recommendation ... and even then there would be multiple equally good answers. I would strongly suspect that you start with XML tutorials, which will go over some of this and give you enough background to make some choices yourself, rather than trying to jump directly into coding.

Comment: Thanks Keshlam for valuable words

Comment: One not so valuable word ... somehow I wrote "suspect" when I meant "suggest". Sorry about that. ("Warning: To avoid damage to reputation, engage mind before putting fingers in gear.")

Answer (score 0):

```
You can parse the XML file using a Java DOM Parser.

you can try this.

try {
    Document document = builder.parse(new FileInputStream("c:\\table.xml"));
} catch (SAXException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

You can refer these links:
http://viralpatel.net/blogs/java-xml-xpath-tutorial-parse-xml/

http://www.journaldev.com/1194/java-xpath-tutorial-with-examples

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have good reason not to use XPATH/XSLT directly.

If you want sql like queries, may be you can take a look at [XQUERY](http://www.w3schools.com/xquery/xquery_intro.asp)

Also, please remember that Xquery doesn't come with JAVA by dafault. You have to download a suitable implementation jar from internet

Answer (score 0):

The answer is probably XQuery, but we can't be sure until we see the question.